# When were equivalence classes formalized?

Tags: equivalence-relations, math-history

Neither [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) nor the first few pages of Google are showing me much about the history of the development of [equivalence classes](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EquivalenceClass.html). When was this notion first formalized?

Comment: Kaplansky told me that Gauss equivalence for binary quadratic forms was the first time this happened, other than given examples such as equality of fractions  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_quadratic_form#Equivalence

Comment: You might want to try this on the history of science and math stackexchange. https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Using Google ngram, the usage in English of “equivalence relation” and “equivalence class” seems to start climbing in the late 1920s.The concept could certainly be used under other names before, of course, but that gives a clear idea of when perhaps modern usage started. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=equivalence+class%2Cequivalence+relation&year_start=1800&year_end=1950&corpus=26&smoothing=3

Comment: (I’d expect it was formalized initially in German, just because so much formalization started there. I just don’t know the correct German terms to search.)

Comment: Of interest: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11229-018-1674-2

Comment: The paper argues that, informally, the 19th century was filled with cases, but never formalized. The 1930s were the big decade. It was a collective stumbling towards the idea, rather than one person’s ingenuity. A 1940 paper by Tukey was the earliest place the author found the notion of equivalence relations and classes were used together. His advisor (1938) had previously used $[x]$ for the equivalence class of $x,$ but hadn’t talked about relations.

Answer (score 1):

As recommended by [Alan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/175602/alan), I asked this question over on [hsm.SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

[Conifold](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/users/55/conifold) captured some of the historical messiness in their [answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/13451/15025). I recommend you read his answer, but the gist is that the notion was being developed near the start of the 20th century. Reference together of the modern name **and** formal definition of equivalence classes existed as early as the 1930's.